# python celery for every work is efficient?

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

I'm making API server with python flask.

In my case, it is real production level, So I have to be careful when developing server.

After google searching, found that celery&redis is suitable for task queueing.

So I installed celery&redis via `pip3 install 'celery[redis]'` and defined task, and run.

Everything was fine, but I got some question about it.

Assume that there is user model. Maybe CRUD for user model like this.

- Register user(with photo)
- Delete user
- Get a single user

In my personal think, only `Register user` need to celery&redis.

Because upload photo can take long time, so it have to treated with asynchronize work.

`Delete user` and `Get a slngle user` just query to db and retreive it.

So it doesn't takes longer time. (it means, do not need to work with celery)

It is right? Or, any missing feature I do not know?

To summarize my question, I want to know that is there any standard for celery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it about right.  You can put whatever processing you want in celery, but the rule that you just used--use celery for things that take a long time--is the one we use most in our production environment.  You can also use celery when you want to scale out an operation across servers more easily.  For example, when scraping a large number of pages, you might want to execute that in parallel to speed up what would otherwise be a long-running task.

Answer (score 0):

I do think there is a great tutorial about this topic.

[using-celery-with-flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)

And you can also check out this [repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-celery-example).